# App Inventor - Run Time Error

Tags: runtime-error, app-inventor

I'm tyring to save new item in the list. I'm using TinyDB. Yet, I get "The operation add items to list cannot accept the arguments" error. Why?

[image]

The new data that I want to add to the list:

> 9M2LM (FROM: 1624 - 1630)

Below is the code:

[image]

Please kindly help me to solve my problem. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some more research. I have come out with my own idea on how to fix the problem. Yet, I'm still not sure whether this is the best solution. By the way, the problem is fix now.

Below is the new code that will fix the problem:

[image]

Hopefully it will be useful.